# ROS library cannot find service built in the same package

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I had experienced a weird issue: I am creating in the same package *a service*, *a library relying on this service*, and some executable.
Whenever I clean my workspace (remove devel and build) and do a casual catkin_make, it is saying my libraries cannot find my generated service.

**BUT** if I source setup.bash do again a catkin_make, source one more time and do catkin_make, it can generate nicely without any error.

My question is: Did I mistook by trying to do everything in the same package? Should I divide or I should change my CMakeLists?

Here is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ndt)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -g -Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roslaunch
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  tf
  message_generation
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
  GpsData.srv
)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)

if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  find_package(roslaunch REQUIRED)
  roslaunch_add_file_check(launch USE_TEST_DEPENDENCIES)
endif()

include_directories(include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(/usr/include)

add_library(ndt_func SHARED library/ndt_func.cpp)
add_library(ndt_func_nogps SHARED library/ndt_func_nogps.cpp)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ndt_func ndt_func_nogps
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs nav_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs cv_bridge
  DEPENDS EIGEN3 PCL OpenCVlibraaries
)

add_executable(ndt_loc src/code/ndt_node.cpp)
target_include_directories(ndt_loc PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(ndt_loc ndt_func ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} /usr/lib/liblas.so)

add_executable(ndt_loc_nogps src/tests/ndt_node_nogps.cpp)
target_include_directories(ndt_loc_nogps PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(ndt_loc_nogps ndt_func_nogps ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} /usr/lib/liblas.so)

add_executable(ndt_loc_ref src/tests/ndt_node_ref.cpp)
target_include_directories(ndt_loc_ref PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(ndt_loc_ref ndt_func_nogps ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} /usr/lib/liblas.so)

add_executable(test_gps src/tests/test_gps.cpp)
add_dependencies(test_gps ${ndt_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(test_gps ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

#add_executable(ndt_map src/ndt_map_node.cpp)
#target_include_directories(ndt_map PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#target_link_libraries(ndt_map ndt_func ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} /usr/lib/liblas.so)

add_executable(ndt_data_transfer src/code/ndt_data_transfer.cpp)
add_dependencies(ndt_data_transfer ${ndt_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(ndt_data_transfer ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(ndt_data_transfer_noscore src/tests/ndt_data_transfer_noscore.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ndt_data_transfer_noscore ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

#add_executable(GPS_message src/code/GPS_message.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(GPS_message ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(DIRECTORY 
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})

install(TARGETS ndt_func
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(TARGETS ndt_loc ndt_loc_nogps ndt_data_transfer ndt_data_transfer_noscore test_gps #ndt_map ndt_loc_gps ndt_loc_ref 
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
)
```

Here the output after cleaning (only for this package):

```
####
#### Running command: "make -j12 -l12" in "/home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer2
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GPUStatus
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserTrajCmd
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DashboardState
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerState
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLaserTrajCmd
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserScannerSignal
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState2
Scanning dependencies of target media_files
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 58%] Built target media_files
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPeriodicCmd
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccelerometerState
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DashboardState
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer2
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserTrajCmd
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerState
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLaserTrajCmd
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserScannerSignal
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GPUStatus
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerBoardState
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState2
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PressureState
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccessPoint
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PeriodicCmd
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 58%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 58%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 58%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 58%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccelerometerState
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer
[ 58%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPeriodicCmd
[ 58%] Generating moc_qnode.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target _qt_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_TwoInts
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 58%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target mt_loc
Scanning dependencies of target ndt_data_transfer_noscore
[ 58%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerBoardState
Scanning dependencies of target _ndt_generate_messages_check_deps_GpsData
[ 58%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PressureState
Scanning dependencies of target ndt_func_nogps
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccessPoint
Scanning dependencies of target ndt_func
Scanning dependencies of target ndt_loc_ums
[ 58%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PeriodicCmd
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target _catkin_empty_exported_target
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 58%] Building CXX object ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_data_transfer_noscore.dir/src/tests/ndt_data_transfer_noscore.cpp.o
[ 59%] Generating qrc_images.cxx
[ 59%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 59%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 59%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[ 59%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 59%] Built target _qt_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_TwoInts
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 59%] Built target _ndt_generate_messages_check_deps_GpsData
[ 59%] Generating ui_main_window.h
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 59%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 59%] Generating moc_main_window.cxx
[ 59%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 59%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 59%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 59%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[ 59%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 59%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[ 59%] Building CXX object mt_loc/CMakeFiles/mt_loc.dir/src/mt_func.cpp.o
[ 59%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 59%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target qtutorials
[ 59%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 59%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 59%] Building CXX object ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_func_nogps.dir/library/ndt_func_nogps.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 60%] Building CXX object ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_func.dir/library/ndt_func.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_py
[ 60%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 60%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[ 60%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 60%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 60%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 61%] Building CXX object ndt_ums/CMakeFiles/ndt_loc_ums.dir/src/ndt_node.cpp.o
[ 61%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 61%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 61%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[ 61%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 61%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 61%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[ 61%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 61%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 61%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 61%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 61%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 61%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Building CXX object qt_ros/qt_tutorials/common/CMakeFiles/qtutorials.dir/main_window.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object qt_ros/qt_tutorials/common/CMakeFiles/qtutorials.dir/qnode.cpp.o
Scanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[ 62%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Building CXX object qt_ros/qt_tutorials/common/CMakeFiles/qtutorials.dir/qrc_images.cxx.o
[ 62%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[ 62%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 62%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 62%] Building CXX object qt_ros/qt_tutorials/common/CMakeFiles/qtutorials.dir/moc_main_window.cxx.o
[ 62%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 62%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Building CXX object qt_ros/qt_tutorials/common/CMakeFiles/qtutorials.dir/moc_qnode.cxx.o
[ 62%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 62%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_Extrinsics
Scanning dependencies of target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_IMUInfo
[ 62%] Built target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_IMUInfo
[ 62%] Built target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_Extrinsics
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target bond_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 62%] Built target bond_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target bond_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 62%] Built target bond_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target bond_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 62%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 62%] Built target bond_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target bond_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
[ 62%] Built target bond_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target nodelet_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target nodelet_generate_messages_eus
[ 62%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
[ 62%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target nodelet_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target bond_generate_messages_py
[ 62%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 62%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Built target bond_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
[ 62%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 62%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
[ 62%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_py
[ 62%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_lisp
[ 62%] Generating Python from MSG realsense2_camera/IMUInfo
Scanning dependencies of target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_eus
[ 62%] Generating Lisp code from realsense2_camera/IMUInfo.msg
[ 62%] Generating EusLisp code from realsense2_camera/IMUInfo.msg
[ 62%] Generating Lisp code from realsense2_camera/Extrinsics.msg
[ 63%] Generating EusLisp code from realsense2_camera/Extrinsics.msg
[ 63%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 64%] Generating Javascript code from realsense2_camera/IMUInfo.msg
[ 64%] Generating Python from MSG realsense2_camera/Extrinsics
[ 64%] Generating EusLisp manifest code for realsense2_camera
[ 64%] Generating Javascript code from realsense2_camera/Extrinsics.msg
[ 64%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target turtlebot_teleop_joy
[ 64%] Building CXX object turtlebot/turtlebot_teleop/CMakeFiles/turtlebot_teleop_joy.dir/src/turtlebot_joy.cpp.o
[ 65%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for realsense2_camera
[ 65%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target turtlebot_description_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 65%] Built target turtlebot_description_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
Scanning dependencies of target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 65%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/LaserScannerSignal.msg
[ 65%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/DashboardState.msg
In file included from /home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/src/ndt_matching/library/ndt_func.cpp:2:0:
/home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/src/ndt_matching/include/ndt_func.h:24:25: fatal error: ndt/GpsData.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_func.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_func.dir/library/ndt_func.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_func.dir/library/ndt_func.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5444: recipe for target 'ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_func.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ndt_matching/CMakeFiles/ndt_func.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 66%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/AccelerometerState.msg
[ 66%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/BatteryServer.msg
[ 66%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/PowerBoardState.msg
[ 66%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/BatteryState.msg
[ 67%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/PressureState.msg
[ 67%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/GPUStatus.msg
[ 67%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/PeriodicCmd.msg
[ 67%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/PowerState.msg
[ 67%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/LaserTrajCmd.msg
[ 68%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/AccessPoint.msg
[ 68%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/BatteryServer2.msg
[ 68%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/BatteryState2.msg
[ 68%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/SetLaserTrajCmd.srv
[ 69%] Generating Lisp code from pr2_msgs/SetPeriodicCmd.srv
[ 69%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_eus
[ 69%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 70%] Linking CXX shared library /home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libqtutorials.so
[ 70%] Built target qtutorials
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable /home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot_teleop/turtlebot_teleop_joy
[ 71%] Built target turtlebot_teleop_joy
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable /home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ndt/ndt_data_transfer_noscore
[ 71%] Built target ndt_data_transfer_noscore
[ 71%] Linking CXX shared library /home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmt_loc.so
[ 71%] Built target mt_loc
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable /home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ndt_ums/ndt_loc_ums
[ 71%] Built target ndt_loc_umslibraarieslibraaries
[ 71%] Linking CXX shared library /home/mobiltech/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libndt_func_nogps.so
[ 71%] Built target ndt_func_nogps
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed
```

I source devel/setup.bash, do catkin_make and get the same error, source one more time and after a third catkin_make:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/ee674acaa31daecec38575abc8abb545

And it is working

*EDIT*

Thanks to @Solrac3589, sourcing the package does not have any effects. Effectively it is a known issue that messages might not be built before the executable. In my case the problem are not the executable but the libraries...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355301/ros-library-cannot-find-service-built-in-the-same-package/) by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed! After reading commentary from @Solrac3589

add_dependencies function is working either for creating executable, but also for libraries.

That is to say I add just one line in my CMakeLists under add_libraries like this:

```
add_library(ndt_func SHARED library/ndt_func.cpp)
add_dependencies(ndt_func ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

Originally posted by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) with karma: 33 on 2020-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-22**:
Hey! great you find the solution! Sorry to not tell anything before!

**Comment by [MCmobil](https://answers.ros.org/users/50706/mcmobil/) on 2020-06-22**:
No! You have been helpful enough, your links allowed me to find the solution, that what I was looking for ;)

Thank you one more time!